# Adding an extra button to Tinymce popup

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need help in adding the browse button to the image poup in Tinymce. 
I only need the div itself, nothing extra.

I'm using Tinymce v4

This is my config:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#id_content",
    plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview media',
    file_browser_callback : "myCustomFileBrowser"
 });
```

The `file_browser_callback` adds the browse button, but it also throws an error every time it is clicked(and I want to avoid that).

Comment: why don't you use a plugin and define the necessary button in the dialog.html there?

Comment: i'm not too familiar with writing plugins for tinymce, i tried their tutorial but it didn't work. my temp solution is that i just removed the code that calls a function in the plugin itself, so now it just adds the button and i bind my own function to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the error message was "TypeError: a is not a function". You need to give the function itself, not a string containing its name.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#id_content",
    plugins: 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview media',
    file_browser_callback: function (inputId, url, type, callerWindow) {
        console.log('store the chosen ' + type + ' URL in #' + inputId);
    }
});
```

or

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#id_content",
    plugins: 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview media',
    file_browser_callback: myCustomFileBrowser
});
```

More details on the interface: [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:file_browser_callback](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3afile_browser_callback)